# vb.net manipulating textbox of what is the current time

Tags: vb.net

how can i manipulate my textbox? **Edit** how will the `form_load` check the time and give the user whats textbox to use?

for like example when its

im thinking the logic of what i need is like this.

```
if its4pm then
textbox.text ="its 4 pm"
else if its10pm then
textbox.text = "its 10 pm"
end if
```

i think its simple but i find it confusing.

i tried this but it gives me an output error

```
    Dim date1 As Date = #7:00:00 AM#
    Dim date2 As Date = #10:00:00 AM#
    Dim date3 As Date = #1:00:00 PM#
    Dim date4 As Date = #4:00:00 PM#
    Dim date5 As Date = #7:00:00 PM#

 If TimeOfDay = date5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "here"
        TextBox6.Text = "here"
    ElseIf TimeOfDay = date4 Then
        TextBox2.Text = "here"
        TextBox7.Text = "here"
    ElseIf TimeOfDay = date3 Then
        TextBox3.Text = "here"
        TextBox8.Text = "here"
    ElseIf TimeOfDay = date2 Then
        TextBox4.Text = "here"
        TextBox9.Text = "here"
    ElseIf TimeOfDay = date1 Then
        TextBox5.Text = "here"
        TextBox10.Text = "here"
    End If
```

**Edit:** the output error im talking about is the if else not working even it don't give me syntax error the `textbox` dont display `"here"`

Comment: Not sure about what you are trying to achieve but I guess simply formatting the current DateTime would be much simpler.

Comment: i tried converting to string the date. but when im at `if else` i got error of string and date cant compare. its something like that

Comment: do you want current (system) datetime on your textbox?

Comment: no i want the form_load to check the time and give the user whats textbox to use

Comment: Instead of using few textboxes (one for special hour) - use one pair of textboxes and change behavior of them based on the time? can you show/tell why you use different textboxes?

Comment: im planning to present this running all the time. the 2 textbox is just to check if the time checking is correct. when its done ill do my work and finish it.

Comment: _it gives me an output error_ - Well, what is the error?  If you want help to your questions, you should at least have the courtesy of providing necessary information -- like the exact text of your errors!   We are not psychic.

Comment: Use the datatype `DateTime` rather than `Date`. Also use the `Hour` property to get the hour of the variable of `TimeOfDay.Hour` or `date5.Hour`

Answer (score 1):

Use Now.Hour.ToString()

```
If Now.Hour.ToString() = "7" Then
     'code
End If
```